# maximum and minimum of a set

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does .99999… = 1?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1)

Example 1.6 on page no 9 in "Elementary Real Analysis" by Bruckner say that " the interval (0,1) has no maximum and minimum as 0 and 1 do not belong to the set."
My doubt is if it is an interval, all the numbers between 0 and 1 are included in the set so, .9999..... is maximum, definitely I am missing some point, but don't know where am I going wrong.  Pls explain.

Comment: what you are missing is that 0.99999999..... = 1

Comment: $.9999..... = 1$, and by definition, $1$ is not a member of $(0,1)$.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1/49#49

Comment: Thanx Andra, Thanx Jonas,

Comment: @Andrea Mori, @Jonas Meyer, Thanx Andra, Thanx Jonas, I am still confused, I will put my question this way, if any set is non-empty (which means it has something) then greatest of that something can be treated as "maximum" of that set, correct? So in above example of interval (0,1), if 1 is not included in the set, but definitely something less than 1 is included (as the set is nonempty), then that number which is less than 1 and not equal to 1 is "maximum" for that interval/set, correct?

Comment: the problem is that given *any* $x<1$ you can always find a $y$ such that $x<y<1$. Therefore the interval $(0,1)$ has no maximum (by definition, the maximum of a set is an element of the set which is no less than any other element of the set)

Comment: @Andrea Mori, Thanx Andrea, your answer cleared this doubt, I will contact you for more in future, take care.

Comment: Andrea, why don't you post your comment as an answer?  This way, your answer can be accepted.