# Are there any other numbers like $0.999\ldots$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

In a manner similar to how the value $1$ can be represented as $0.(9)$ too, are there any other values that exhibit this property when represented in base 10?

Comment: Every number that has a terminating decimal expansion has a decimal expansion with a tail of $9$s. E.g., $0.5= 0.499999\cdots$.

Comment: You should try to understand [limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_(mathematics)) and [infinite series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)) if you want to know what such representations even mean in the first place.

Comment: only infinitely many...

Comment: Since only examples between $0$ and $1$ have been posted so far: $2100 = 2099.999\ldots$

Comment: @Rahul: Oddly enough, someone commented with examples larger than 1 but deleted it.

Comment: Jeeze, why edit this century old question? and also another question invovling 0.999999999999999....

Comment: Looks like this person wants to invent a .999 tag and is adding it to these old questions. I'm not sure I agree with it but there it is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any number that ends in an infinite series of $9$'s is equal to the number changing all the $9$'s to $0$'s and incrementing the previous place by $1$.  So $0.5=0.4999\ldots , 0.1328=0.132799999\ldots$ etc.

Answer (score 10):

Every repeating decimal can be represented as a fraction.

Example: Represent $0.\overline{25}$ as a fraction.

First, let $x = 0.\overline{25}$.

Next, multiply both sides of the equation by a power of ten to move the decimal place after the first repeat. In this case, I should choose 100 and get $$100x = 25.\overline{25}.$$

Notice that since there are an infinite number of 25's after the decimal place in $0.\overline{25}$, moving two of them in front of the decimal still leaves an infinite number of them after the decimal. That means we can write that as $$100x = 25 + x.$$

Now we can solve this for $x$.

$$
\begin{align*}
99x &= 25\\
x &= \frac{25}{99}
\end{align*}
$$

So, $x$ is both equal to $0.\overline{25}$ and $\frac{25}{99}$. That must mean $0.\overline{25} = \frac{25}{99}$.

Comment: This isn't really what my question was about, but now I know where the rules to convert repeating decimal fractions to ordinary ones come from. :)

Comment: @Paul, then I guess my answer isn't really about your question either! Hope it helps, in any case.

Comment: @Paul I interpreted your question as "Are there any other repeating decimals that can be represented as fractions?" Was that not what you intended?

Comment: @Austin I know all rational fractions can be represented as both decimal and ordinary fractions. (I also know that if an ordinary cannot be precisely represented as a decimal, that is a limitation of the number base, not a property of the value.) My question was about numbers that, from an infinitezimal point of view, should not represent the same value, but which in actuality they do.

Answer (score 3):

To generalize Austin's answer (and since I don't know what "this property" is, exactly): 
The number $0.\overline{a_1a_2...a_n}$ is equal to $ \frac{ a_1a_2 ... a_n}{99\dots9}$, where there are $n$ nines in the denominator.

So $0. \overline{23} = 23/99$

$0. \overline{123} = 123/999 = 61/333$

Comment: And I can't, for the *life* of me, figure out how to fix that LaTex. I intended for there to be 99....9 in the denominator (which could be more precisely represented as nine times a sum of powers of ten...)

Comment: Or a power of ten minus one.

Comment: Thanks, Brian! And @anon, let's not get into another discussion *a lá* http://math.stackexchange.com/q/11/7850 :)

Comment: The number $0.\overline{a_{p-1}a_{p-2}\ldots a_{1}a_{0}}$ is the sum of a geometric series

$$0.\overline{a_{p-1}a_{p-2}\ldots a_{1}a_{0}}=\dfrac{N}{10^{p}}+\dfrac{N}{10^{2p}}+\cdots =\dfrac{N/10^{p}}{1-10^{-p}}=\dfrac{N}{10^{p}-1},$$

where

$$N=10^{0}a_{0}+10^{1}a_{1}+\cdots +10^{p-1}a_{p-1}.$$

Answer (score 2):

I seem to recall reading somewhere (therefore it's true!! (?)) that Johannes Kepler proposed a base-3 numeral system with three digits: $0$, $1$, and $-1$.  In that system, the number $1/2$ can be represented in two different ways:
$$
1.,\ -1,\ -1,\ -1,\ \ldots,
$$
and
$$
0.,\ 1,\ 1,\ 1, \ \ldots\ .
$$
And similarly for every binary rational number (i.e. rational number whose denominator is a power of $2$).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_ternary