# Why is the probability that a bottle contains exactly one liter of water equal to zero?

Tags: probability-theory, recreational-mathematics

Let X be a continuous random variable, where X is the amount of water in a bottle in milliliters. The probability that there is between $900$ milliliters and $1100$ milliliters of water in the bottle is given by the following equation:

$P(900 ≤ X ≤ 1100) = \int\limits_{900}^{1100}f(x)dx$,

where $f(x)$ is the probability density function. Thus, if we want to know the probability that there is exactly one liter of water in the bottle we look at the following equation:

$P(1000 ≤ X ≤ 1000) = \int\limits_{1000}^{1000}f(x)dx$

Obviously, $\int\limits_{1000}^{1000}f(x)dx = 0$. So the probability that X is exactly $1000$, $1100$ or any value you choose, is always equal to zero. Note that this is true for continuous random variables and not for discrete random variables.

**Question:** What's the general intuition behind $P(X = 1000) = 0$? I always thought that it had to do with the fact that the random variable was continuous; for every $\epsilon > 0$, I can find a value between $1000$ and $1000 + \epsilon$. This illustrates how unlikely it is to pick **exactly** $1000$, but I don't know if this correct.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well, this a good start to study measure theory~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose a point from it-with uniform distribution-the odds of choosing any single point on the set is $0$.

Intuitively, it means that is not impossible, but it is highly improbable.

For example see this answer/question: "[Is it generally accepted that if you throw a dart at a number line you will NEVER hit a rational number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155156/is-it-generally-accepted-that-if-you-throw-a-dart-at-a-number-line-you-will-neve/155159#155159)"

Comment: $\mathcal L ([900,1100])=1100-900>0$

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Lebesgue outer measure obviously..

Comment: Sorry, but I'm confused. Any set that has outer measure zero is Lebesgue-measurable and has Lebesgue measure zero. Moreover the Lebesgue measure is the same as the outer measure whenever the former is defined.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Done