# Clarification on Nonstandard Analysis: Is $0.\overline{9}=1$, is it not, or is there some subtlety that allows both interpretations?

Tags: reference-request, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

*This, I hope, is not a duplicate; I am exercising my critical thinking here and I want to understand what going on, and the available content I have found online on this so far has not helped.*

I'm getting conflicting information regarding whether $1=0.\overline{9}$ (*i.e.*, "$0$ point $9$ recurring") holds in nonstandard analysis.

On one hand, we have this comment:

> Simply speaking, NSA does not lead to conclusions about $\Bbb R$ that differ from those of standard analysis. Giving alternate definitions of $0.99…$ is not really the concern of most researchers working in NSA: we roll with the usual definition (as in Rudin above), and so $0.999⋯=1$.

This was found here:

[Reference request: How is $0.99\cdots$ defined in nonstandard analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653526/reference-request-how-is-0-99-cdots-defined-in-nonstandard-analysis#comment7509468_3653526)

---

On the other hand, we have:

[About 0.999... = 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/281492/104041)

In that question and its answers, the number

> $$0.9_N:=\sum_{i=1}^N 9\cdot 10^{-i} $$
>
> where $N\in{}^*\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ is an infinite nonstandard natural number

is defined and it is shown that $1-0.9_N$ is a positive infinitesimal number.

---

Both seem reasonable to me, so what gives?

### The Question:

> Does $1=0.\overline{9}$ in nonstandard analysis? Does the question make sense; that is, is there an issue of interpretation or something that leads to these two seemingly opposing responses? Please would someone settle the matter with references?

### Thoughts:

My best and only guess is that $0.9_N$ is not the standard definition of $0.\overline{9}$. I don't understand how though.

It is my understanding that

$$0.\overline{9}:=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^n}.$$

---

*Edit:* As explained in [this comment of mine below](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4711902/clarification-on-nonstandard-analysis-is-0-overline9-1-is-it-not-or-is-t?noredirect=1#comment9977962_4711902), I suppose the problem is that I don't get why

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^n}$$

is not implicit in

$$\sum_{i=1}^N 9\cdot 10^{-i} $$

for infinite $N$.

Comment: You wrote "I don't understand how". Is there a book/source you have that defines $0.\overline{9}$ in a way similar to $0.9_N$? If not, then that's how - no one defined them similarly, so there's no reason to expect they're the same. If so, then adding a quote from that source to your post would greatly clarify where your confusion comes from.

Comment: I have added what I believe is the standard definition of $0.\overline{9}$, @MarkS.

Comment: You've written two different (but similar) definitions. And I see nowhere in your question or links that anyone has claimed they're the same/both definitions of $0.\overline 9$. So I'm not sure where your question lies. Is there a sentence somewhere in your links that you read as suggesting that the definition of one could be a definition of the other? Is there a question you have about either definition and/or conventions about $0.\overline 9$ not addressed by the other questions on this site? I'm not trying to be difficult, just trying the pinpoint the confusion so I might help.

Comment: I'm not sure, @MarkS., but, like I said, I think that's what the problem is: they're different definitions. But how is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^n}$$ not implicit by $$\sum_{i=1}^N 9\times 10^{-i}$$ for infinite $N$?

Comment: I have made an edit, @MarkS. Please do write an answer, even if someone beats you to it.

Comment: My comment (that your question cites) is followed immediately by  *That said, "simply speaking" is necessarily inaccurate: questions of mathematical culture tend to be subtle rather than from simple. There are many possible alternative semantics for decimal notation that nonstandard analysis can formalize, and some good (social) reasons for adopting them. The reference you are looking for is the article [When is .999... less than 1?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1007.3018) by K. U. Katz and M. Katz...* Have you read the linked article? You should, because I think it thoroughly answers your question.

Comment: Yes, I saw that @Z.A.K. I guess it didn't register to me as an answer to my question, but instead as further clarification on the question it is under; I'm sorry. I haven't read the article yet.

Comment: I think GEdgar's answer is good, but you also asked for a reference, so I will recommend Rob Goldblatt's _Lectures on the Hyperreals_, which is very readable. In particular it will give you a good sense of the transfer principle, which is the key notion you seem to be missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Setup

#### Aside

Aside: This isn't relevant to the main thrust of your question, but
I wanted to note that there are many different equivalent definitions
of $0.\overline{9}$, depending on how exactly the real numbers are
set up. For instance, in some texts that expression would not be defined
as a summation of any kind, but rather would signify something like
"the unique real number in all of the intervals $\left[0,1\right]$,
$\left[0.9,1\right]$, $\left[0.99,1\right]$, ...".

For the rest of this answer, I will assume the summation definitions
$0.\overline{9}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}$
and $0.9_{N}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}$ where
$N\in{}^*\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ is an infinite nonstandard
natural number.

#### Approach

I will be splitting this answer into three levels requiring the reader
to be comfortable with more "advanced" mathematics for each level,
but it is hard to target every person's mathematical background, so
please comment if some detail should be added somewhere.

---

### Pre-calculus

$0.\overline{9}$ means the real number that $0.9$, $0.9+0.09=0.99$,
$0.9+0.09+0.009=0.999$ are getting closer to. As discussed in many
other places on the internet, including [the English Wikipedia article
for 0.999...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...), the number it's getting closer to is $1$.

However, in some branches of mathematics, there are ways to imagine/define
new "numbers" that are not real numbers, which nonetheless can
be compared to real numbers. "Numbers" like $0.9_{N}$ are less
than $1$, but closer to it than any real number less than $1$ could
be.

---

### Calculus

#### A definition of $0.\overline{9}$

In an expression like ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}$,
the $\infty$ symbol on the summation sign is a shorthand for evaluating
a certain limit. Specifically, we evaluate the limit of the sequence
of finite partial sums: ${\displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty}}\left({\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{m}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}\right)$.
And here, this $\infty$ symbol means something that can be explained
using only everyday real numbers, which are always finite. Specifically,
this limit is a number $L$ so that for every error tolerance $\varepsilon>0$,
we can choose a natural number $M$ big enough so that if $m\ge M$,
the finite sum is "$\varepsilon$-close to $L$" - i.e. that $\left|{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{m}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}-L\right|<\varepsilon$.

We know from our experience with geometric series that the limit $L$
should be $\dfrac{9/10}{1-(1/10)}=1$ in this case. And this works out with the $\varepsilon$
definition. For example, if $\varepsilon=0.003$, then we can choose
$M=3$ since $\left|{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{3}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}-1\right|=\left|0.999-1\right|=0.001<0.003=\varepsilon$
and $\left|{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{4}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}-1\right|=\left|0.9999-1\right|=0.0001<0.003=\varepsilon$,
etc.
(In fact, we can handle any $\varepsilon$ by taking $M$ to
be the [ceiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $\log_{10}\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon}$.)

I emphasize again that the above discussion did not involve any infinite
numbers, just a symbol $\infty$ which was a directive to do certain
work with finite inequalities.

#### The idea of $0.9_{M}$

Without getting into the weeds of details, there are ways to add on
new "numbers" to the naturals and to the reals which get the name
"nonstandard". For instance, there could be an infinitesimal "number"
$c$ that's smaller than all of $0.1$, $0.01$, $0.001$, ..., but
still greater than $0$ (no real number is like that). It turns out
that some numbers like $1-c$ where $c$ is a certain kind of infinitesimal
might be deserving of a name and symbols that evoke a similar idea
to the summation of $0.0\ldots09$s we did earlier. But those are different
"numbers" than $1$, the only real number close to those finite
sums.

Just like summation had a special unintuitive meaning when the symbol
on top was $\infty$, it has a *different* special unintuitive
meaning when the symbol on top is "an infinite nonstandard natural
number", whatever that is. The precise meaning of ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}$ is not only different than ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}$, but also depends on which system of nonstandard numbers we're working with, and which "infinite nonstandard natural" number $N$ is
within that system.

You can learn about this on an informal level in Keisler's free textbook [Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Ehkeisler/calc.html).

---

### Analysis

To really compare these two expressions, one of which only makes sense
in a context of non-standard analysis, it's best to view each of them
through that same lens. This will take a bit of development/statements
of basic facts about non-standard analysis, but I'll try to thread
the needle in only being detailed enough to address the original question,
rather than write a proper development of nonstandard analysis.

#### Hyperreals

Probably the most hands-on approach to constructing "nonstandard"
numbers is to create [Robinson's Hyperreals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number)
via [an ultrapower construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperreal_number#The_ultrapower_construction).

Quoting my other answers about hyperreals here:

> For those unfamiliar, the basic idea behind of the construction isn't
> too complicated. I like [Terry Tao's voting
> analogy](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/06/25/ultrafilters-nonstandard-analysis-and-epsilon-management/).
> A hyperreal is a sequence of reals (well, an [equivalence
> class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) of sequences)
> that vote each time you ask about a property (like "are
> you bigger than $5$?" ). How to determine which infinite
> collections of voters count as good majorities is handled by some
> technical stuff, but you don't have to worry about that to get the
> idea.

One important property (which would require more details to make precise
and prove) is that essentially any functions/operations that you can apply
to reals (or a relevant subset, like the naturals), can be applied
to these hyperreals: just do everything entry
by entry (for any representative of the equivalence class). For example,
$x=\left[\left(1,2,3,\ldots\right)\right]$ is an "infinite nonstandard
natural" (since a majority of the entries would agree that it's
greater than $17$, etc.). And if you want to square it, just square
each entry to get $x^{2}=\left[\left(1,4,9,\ldots\right)\right]$.
Since $4>2$, $9>3$, etc., we have $x^{2}>x$.

Another key property is that if a hyperreal is finite (a majority
of the entries are bounded between two finite reals), then there is
a closest real number to it. This is sometimes called the "standard
part" or the "shadow" of the original hyperreal.

#### What is $0.9_{N}$?

In order to interpret something like "$0.9_{N}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}$
where $N\in{}^*\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{N}$ is an infinite nonstandard
natural number.", we need to define finite summations, and use that
to understand what this should mean. For instance, there is a finite
sum function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f\left(m\right)={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{m}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}$.
And an infinite nonstandard natural is like a sequence where all (or
at least a "majority") of the entries are naturals, and that no
majority of the entries are bounded. $x$ and $x^{2}$ from the previous
paragraph are examples of these. So given $N=x^{2}=\left[\left(1,4,9,\ldots\right)\right]$,
we can define the sum $0.9_{N}={\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}$
to be $f\left(N\right)$, which is $\left[\left(0.9,0.9999,0.999\,999\,999,\ldots\right)\right]$.
If we instead had $N=x=\left[\left(1,2,3,\ldots\right)\right]$, then
$f\left(N\right)$ would be $\left[\left(0.9,0.99,0.999,\ldots\right)\right]$,
which is a smaller number, since $0.99<0.9999$ and $0.999<0.999\,999\,999$,
etc. But all of these possibilities for various values of $N$ are
still less than $1=\left[\left(1,1,1,\ldots\right)\right]$, since
$0.9\ldots9<1$ for any finite amount of $9$s you put there. For
this reason, something like $0.9_{N}$ is different from $1$.

#### Limits via Hyperreals

A reason to develop something like the hyperreals is that they give
you a way to develop calculus/analysis that more closely resembles
intuition about infinitesimal quantities held by Fermat and Leibniz.
There are translations of definitions of limits, derivatives, integrals,
etc. into discussions of infinite/infinitesimal hyperreals.

For our purposes, we just need to worry about the limit of a sequence.
If $\left(a_{1},a_{2},\ldots\right)$ is a sequence, then the function
$a\left(m\right)=a_{m}$ is a function on the positive integers, which
we could apply to infinite nonstandard naturals like $x$ or $x^{2}$.
If the closest real number to $a\left(N\right)$ is $L$ no matter
what infinite nonstandard natural we pick, then we say that ${\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}}a_{n}=L$.
It turns out that this agrees with the $\varepsilon$ definition discussed
earlier.

This means that ${\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}={\displaystyle \lim_{m\to\infty}}{\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{m}}\dfrac{9}{10^{n}}$
is basically saying "what is the closest real to any of the possibilities
for $0.9_{N}$?". And the answer to *that* is just $1=0.\overline{9}$.

#### Conclusion

$0.9_{N}$ is some weird hyperreal/nonstandard real which is infinitesimally close to $1$, leveraging that $N$ is a particular infinite quantity. But the use of the $\infty$ symbol means that we are no longer working with a particular infinite quantity, just asking which everyday real number all of those $0.9_{N}$s are close to, which is $1$.

### "Infinite $N$"

This question hinged on "$\infty$" and "infinite $N$" both pointing to a concept of infinity, and the distinction between them. There are actually very many different concepts of infinity, and it can be challenging and rewarding to keep the distinctions and connections straight. You can read summaries of them in [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3506355/26369) to the MathSE question [Understanding infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1071681/26369).

Answer (score 6):

First,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^n} = 1 .
\tag1$$
Non-standard analysis does not change this (standard) fact.
In a hyperreal field ${}^*\mathbb R$, we see that if $N$ is an infinite natural number, then
$$
1- \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{9}{10^n}\text{ is positive but infinitesimal.}
$$
What we do know is: the following are eqivalent:
$$
(a)\quad\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^n} = 1
$$
and
$$
(b)\quad\text{for all infinite natural numbers $N$, }\left|1- \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{9}{10^n}\right|
\text{ is infinitesimal.}
$$

---

What do we mean by
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{9}{10^n}\qquad?
\tag2$$
It seems to be a sum with infinitely many terms, which is nonsense.  Here is Robinson's explanation.  Take the (standard) function $S : \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ defined by
$$
S(n) = \sum_{n=1}^n \frac{9}{10^n} .
$$
There is a corresponding non-standard object, say ${}^*S$ with ${}^*S : {}^*\mathbb N \to {}^*\mathbb R$.  (The main usfulness of non-standard analysis is this "transfer principle".) Then $(2)$ is by definition: ${}^*S\; ( N)$.

If we merely have a non-archimedian ordered field $F$, then $(2)$ is undefined.  To make $(2)$ meaningful, we require this particular field ${}^*\mathbb R$, with its corresponding transfer principle.

*Reference*
*Robinson, Abraham*, Non-standard analysis, Princeton, NJ: Princeton Univ. Press. xix, 293 p. (1996). [ZBL0843.26012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0843.26012).

Comment: My question is a bit redundant, but I think it's worth stressing/highlighting. I'm somewhat perplexed by the use of "$\infty$" and "$N$" in the top of the summation sign. Am I correct that say that the $\infty$ sign does not represent any value whatsoever (in the hyperreal field) and $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} $$ represents the the limit of partial sums as in the standard definition (that you can find in any standard real analysis book)? And am I correct in thinking that $N$ actually stands for a genuine object of the hyperreal field and $$ \sum_{n=1}^{N} $$ is as defined in your post?

Comment: @MaximalIdeal , as sort of explored in my answer, there's not just one thing that $\infty$ means, in the sense that the definition found in any standard analysis book is *equivalent* to a definition in terms of *all* genuine objects that are "infinite nonstandard naturals" in a hyperreal field.

Comment: @MarkS. Ok, I appreciate the comprehensive post.

Answer (score 2):

Once you define $0.999\ldots$ as "$0$ point $9$ recurring" there is no ambiguity and one must conclude that it equals $1$ (in this case there is no final $9$).  The definition in terms of "$0$, point, followed by an infinite string of $9$s" is more ambiguous and enables an interpretation according to which the number of $9$s is an infinite (more precisely, unlimited) integer $H$ in the sense of nonstandard analysis (in this case there is a *final* $9$).  Such a number will have standard part $1$, but will fall short of $1$ by an infinitesimal amount.  It seems to me that the (many) students who believe that $0.999\ldots<1$ usually have some intuitive naive version of the latter interpretation in mind.  The traditional approaches to the calculus do not possess a sufficiently rich language to formalize such student intuitions.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I'm surprised there's such a thing as a "*final* $9$" in such a case! That's really interesting. Where can I find out more?

Comment: There are two approaches to nonstandard analysis: (1) the model-theoretic approach along the lines of Robison's original approach, and (2) axiomatic approaches.  The advantage of the latter is that it can be *effective*.  There is a fairly elementary explanation of this in the recent article in *Real Analysis Exchange*; see https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.09672