# Can someone help me solve this problem please.

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

For the real numbers $x=0.9999999\dots$ and $y=1.0000000\dots$ it is the case that $x^2<y^2$. Is it true or false? Prove if you think it's true and give a counterexample if you think it's false.

Comment: Are there dots after the digits '9' or aren't there?

Comment: yes there are, the dot represent that it will going forever

Comment: Solved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/287311/73324) but also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/281492/73324), depending on your mathematical sophistication.

Comment: How so counterexample? There is absolutely nothing to choose in this question, so it is just a true or false question (in fact false), no example is involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x=y$ (that is, $y = 0.\overline{9}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac9{10^n}=1=x$), it must be the case that $x^2=y^2$.  Thus, your statement is false.