# Correct $(0.11111111...)_{2}=(10)_{2}$?

Tags: number-theory

My question is if it is possible to claim that $(0.11111111...)_{2}=(10)_{2}$

Here is my approach. I started out by trying to convert this recurring number to base 10. This can be expressed as a sum, i.e.,
$$\sum{\frac{1}{2^n} } = 1 + \frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...\frac{1}{2^n}$$
This turns out to be a convergent sum, hence,
$$\sum{\frac{1}{2^n} } = \frac{1}{1-0.5}=2$$
This means that the recurring number in base 2 is equal to 2 in base 10. However, 2 in base 10 can be expressed as 10 in base 2, or with other words,
$$(0.11111111...)_{2}=(2)_{10}$$
$$(2)_{10}=(10)_2$$
$$(0.11111111...)_{2}=(10)_2$$
$$QED$$
Do you agree with my reasoning?

Comment: In your first sum, the 1 should not be there; it should start with $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This is like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1 except with base 2

Comment: Not quite. It basically asks if 1 = 2.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Josh B., Joe Z. and lab bhattacharjee!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error. Your $\displaystyle \sum \frac{1}{2^n}$ is counting from $n = 0$ when it should be counting from $n = 1$.

So in reality, the convergent sum is $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1/2}{1 - 1/2} = 1$, as expected.

Answer (score 4):

It would be correct except that the sum starts with $1$, so your claim should be $(1.111\ldots)_2=(10)_2$

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Ross Millikan!