# Why is counting with infinity not indeterminable?

Tags: infinity

I was trying to find a function that looks like square root of x but I wanted to limit that function from above to 1. Finding solution was not as hard as I thought, but...

When I was thinking about solution I was thinking about infinity, because function of square root is not limited from above. So my first question was: **How do I limit something that can be infinite?**

Than I crossed to some page that gave me an idea: **I can make two square root functions that will be offset and subtract one from the other**.

$$ f(x) = -\left(\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}\right)+1$$

Okay that worked. I got function that does exactly what I want, but I don't know why. I mean, it should not...? Main reason of my confusion is that $\infty - \infty = \text{indeterminable}$, but in my case is not...?

But that is not the only case. I also tried
$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} (x+1)-x $
and than also the most simple case
$ x-x; x = \infty $.
It turns out that $ \infty - \infty = 0 $.

> Both on [Wolfram Alfa](https://wolframalpha.com)

Could you explain in little more detail why? or what am I doing or thinking wrong about?

---

But I guest I though about it all wrong. 
The theory or sentence $ \infty - \infty = \text{undefined} $ is about two different infinity which cannot be subtracted because we are unable to know the outcome while in my case there is only one infinity and therefore $ \infty - \infty = 0 $.

Comment: Infinity is not a real number.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number, so you can't plug “$x=\infty$” into the formulas. The phrase “indeterminate form” refers to calculation of **limits** as $x \to \infty$, as explained in the answers to this question, for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554521/what-really-is-an-indeterminate-form

Comment: An indeterminate form does not mean the limit can never be computed. $\frac{x}x$ is surely an indeterminate form at $\infty$ if I work independently on the numetor and denominator, but, for $x>0$, this function is just $1$.

Comment: By the way, nice candidates for the function shape you're looking for could be $x/(x+1)$ or $\sqrt{x/(x+1)}$.

Comment: Warning, $\lim_{x\to\infty}((x+1)-x)\ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\infty-\infty$ does not mean that you "subtract infinity from infinity", which is just meaningless.

If signifies that you are studying an expression which appears as the difference between two functions, $f(x)-g(x)$, when these are both unbounded (when $x$ approaches some predefined finite value, or goes to infinity).

For example,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}(x^2-x)$$ and

$$\lim_{x\to3}\left(\frac1{x-3}-\frac1{\sin(x-3)}\right)$$ and
do have this form.

Depending on the situation, the difference can be unbounded, tend to a particular finite value or even fail to tend to a single value.