# Prove that $\lfloor0.999\dots\rfloor= ?$ $0$ or $1$?

Tags: limits, decimal-expansion

I think $\lfloor0.999\dots\rfloor= 1$, as $0.999\dots=1$,but I have doubt, as $\lfloor0.9\rfloor=0$,$\lfloor0.99\rfloor=0$,$\lfloor0.9999999\rfloor=0$, etc.

Comment: @Ross This is not a duplicate...

Comment: @user1729, Thanks.

Comment: (Or rather, the OP is wanting to understand the flaw in their argument rather than just "I want a proof of this fact!".)

Comment: This is a good question. Thanks

Comment: Induction allows you to prove a statement about an infinite number of finite cases, it does not (usually) tell you anything about the infinite case itself.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your first assertion is correct. The other observation just says that the function $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor$ is not continuous.

Comment: Thanks for so quick reply and additional information.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 11):

For one thing, $0.999...$ is exactly equal to $1$.

To prove that $0.999... = 1$, we use sums of infinite geometric sequences. We know that
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty r^k = \frac{1}{1-r} \forall \;\left|r\right|\lt1$$
It is fairly simple to prove this statment, although I won't go into that.
For our specific instance, we have
$$0.999... = \frac{9}{10}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{10})^k = \frac{9}{10} \cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}} = \frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{10}{9}=1$$

Using the substitution property, we can substitute any alternate representation of a number into an equation, and it will yield the same result. Therefore,

$$\lfloor0.999...\rfloor = \lfloor1\rfloor = 1$$

Comment: For more proofs, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1).