# What's wrong with my method that gives $0.\bar9 = 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

This is what I learned :

$x = 0.\bar3$ (I)

$10x=3.\bar3$ (II)

(II)-(I) :   $9x = 3  => x = 1/3.$ And It's OK.

But now, I think this similar calculation gives me wrong answer:

$x = 0.\bar9$  (I)

$10x=9.\bar9$ (II)

(II)-(I) :   $9x = 9  => x = 1$

Why does: $0.\bar9 = 1 $  ?

Comment: This is true, take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1 .

Comment: @Stefan Thanks ! I got the point !