# Decimal expansion of a fraction

Tags: decimal-expansion

I was reading something which I found really special. It goes like this : Imagine we have a line with unity division (0,1,2,etc.) Now, we have a point on this line. The point can be on a point of division or it can be contained between two points of division. If it isn't on a point of division, then we can continue cutting the line into 10 equal pieces. (The first piece being 0, the second 1, the third 2,...) So, if my point was between 1 and 2, I'll have 1.0,1.1,etc. We continue this cutting until our point arrives at a point of division.If this arrives, we have two choices : We can pick the interval on the left or the interval on the right. And we can continue this way at infinity.

We also have the following formulae to express our numbers : g+a/10+a2/100+a3/1000+...
g being an integer and a being the number of the piece which contains our point.

Now, my question concerns this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rszUH.jpg

How can it be possible that we can have 1/4=0.2499... and 1/4=0.25000... Also, for this idea to be valid, must it necessarily be an infinite decimal expansion or I could have the following 1/4=0.249 and 1/4=0.250 ?

Thank you !

Comment: $0.2499999...$ equals $0.25$, just like [0.99999...=1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-999999999-1)

Answer (score 1):

The point here is that the two real numbers $$0.24999... \text{ and } 0.25000...$$ are the same. There are a couple of ways to see this. Let's just consider the number $$r=0.9999...$$ we can demonstrate that this is actually equal to 1: $$10r-r = 9$$ $$9r=9$$ $$r=1$$

If that isn't convincing, you can view this in terms of a geometric series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 9 \cdot 10^{-n} = 9 \frac{10^{-1}}{1-10^{-1}} = 9 \cdot \frac{1}{9} = 1$$

Or finally from the definition of real numbers as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences of rational numbers, we see that the two sequences $$\{0.9, 0.99, 0.999, ...\} \text{ and } \{1, 1, 1, 1,... \}$$ are in the same equivalence class. Thus the two real numbers are the same.

Comment: Your first argument is circular.

Comment: It's not circular. We are assuming that $r$ is equal to the real number $0.999...$, and then using the field properties of the real numbers to demonstrate the identity $0.999...=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Real numbers are usually defined
by a process or algorithm.
This process produces
a series of numbers
$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
(usually rational,
or else the definition
of real numbers
is circular).

This series is said to *converge*
if (using Cauchy's definition)
for any $c>0$
there is a $N(c)$ such that
for all $n, m > N(c)$,
$\mid a_n-a_m \mid
< c
$.

Two of these processes,
say
$(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$
and
$(b_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$,
are said to
represent the same real number
if
for any $c>0$
there is a $N(c)$ such that
for all $n > N(c)$,
$\mid a_n-b_n \mid
< c
$.

This is why
the sequences
$(1, 1, 1, ...)$
and 
$(.9, .99, .999, ...)$
represent the same real number:
because
$a_n-b_n = \frac1{10^n}
\to 0$.

You can do the same thing
using Dedekind cuts
(as in Landau's page-turner
"Foundations of Analysis")
but I find that
Cauchy is easier to explain
(and also has fewer letters).