# Number between less than 15 or equal to 15 or between the two options?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

Is $14.9999999$ ad infinitum $\lt 15$, $= 15$, or in between?

Comment: Can you find a real number between $14.\overline{9}$ and $15$?  Would you expect to be able to if they were different?  Also, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-999999999-1

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly $15$, in the same way that $0.999 \ldots = 1$.
For my second affirmation, notice that $1/3 = 0.333\ldots$, then $1 = 3/3 = 3 \cdot 0.333\ldots = 0.999\ldots$.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely equal. It's a sum of a geometric series:

$$14.9999\cdots =14+\frac9{10}\left(1 + \frac1{10}+\frac1{10^2}+\cdots\right)
$$

$$=14+\frac9{10}\left(\frac1{1-\frac1{10}}\right)
$$

$$=14+\frac9{10}\left(\frac{10}9\right)
$$

$$=14+1$$

$$=15$$

as desired.