# Are these proofs logically equivalent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Here are two proofs, firstly:

```
x = 0.999...
10x = 9.999...
    = 9 + 0.999...
    = 9 + x
9x = 9
x = 1
```

And secondly:

```
x = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 ...
  = 1 - (1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 ...
  = 1 - x
2x = 1
x = 1/2
```

The fourth line in the first and the third line in the second use the same trick. Does the legitimacy of the first proof guarantee that of the second?

Comment: No. The series x = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 ... is not convergent. The same trick can not be used, if the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Why can't it be used?

Comment: According to the theory of infinite series.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-999999999-1)

Answer (score 4):

The first proof is also more subtle than it seems. If $x=0.999\dotsc$, then why $10x=9.999\dotsc$? If you have a terminating decimal number, say $x=0.999$, then you can write $$x=\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}+\frac{9}{1000},$$ and then by well-known rules of arithmetic, you have 
$$10x=10\left(\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}+\frac{9}{1000}\right)=\frac{9}{1}+\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}=9.99.$$ But what about non-terminating numbers? It would seem that if $x=0.999\dotsc$ then you can just write 
$$x=\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}+\frac{9}{1000}+\dotsb,$$ but how do you calculate this infinite sum? It is *not* obvious that you can do it because for example the sum $$1-1+1-1+\dotsb$$ does not have an obvious or intuitive value. For example, it could be zero: $$1-1+1-1+\dotsb = (1-1)+(1-1)+\dotsb=0+0+\dotsb = 0,$$ or it could be one: $$1-1+1-1+\dots = 1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\dotsb = 1+0+0+\dotsb = 1$$ or something else.

Now, once you have a definition for calculating (some) infinite sums, you must prove that with that definition $$10\left(\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}+\frac{9}{1000}\dotsb\right)=\frac{9}{1}+\frac{9}{10}+\frac{9}{100}+\dotsb=9.999\dotsc$$ So, there is quite a bit of stuff hidden (or forgotten) in the first proof. The above examples about $1-1+1-1+\dotsb$ being zero or one shows that with infinite sums you must prove even basic "intuitive facts" because they might not actually hold!

*If* with your definition of infinite sums you can prove $$1-1+1-1+\dotsb = 1-(1-1+1-1+\dotsb),$$ then your second proof is also valid. It also shows that whatever definition for $1-1+1-1+\dotsb$ you come up with, if it has the above property, then it must give this sum the value 1/2. However, while the standard definition of infinite sums does give a value for $9/10+9/100+\dotsb$ and has the properties we want, it does not give any value to $1-1+1-1+\dotsb$, so you cannot use that, as others have mentioned.

Comment: I reject the standard definition, why shouldn't I?

Comment: Alright now good luck proving $1−1+1−1+\cdots=1−(1−1+1−1+\cdots)$ with whatever new definition you decide to take.

Comment: The RHS has one more term than the LHS.

Comment: It is your assertion not mine.

Comment: The LHS has 4, the RHS has 5!

Comment: No, the LHS has 1 and the RHS has 2, which is no problem as the equation 1/2 = 1 - 1/2 shows :)

Comment: nonpop clearly has more patience than I.

Comment: Nah, while I'm fine with someone using non-standard definitions, if they keep coming up I will demand a reference for them before continuing.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The first series is absolutely convergent, so its terms can be rearranged without changing the sum, while the second series is divergent.

The number $0.\overline{9}$ can be expressed in the form

\begin{align*}
0.\overline{9} & = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{10^k}\\
               & = \frac{9}{10} \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^k}
\end{align*}
which is a convergent geometric series, so 
\begin{align*}
0.\overline{9} & = \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{10}}\\
               & = \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{\dfrac{9}{10}}\\
               & = \frac{9}{10} \cdot \frac{10}{9}\\
               & = 1
\end{align*}

In fact, the series 
$$0.\overline{9} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{10^k}$$
is absolutely convergent since the series 
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \bigg| \frac{9}{10^K} \bigg| = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{10^k}$$
converges.  Any rearrangement of an absolutely convergent series has the same sum.

The series

$$1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k$$

diverges since the sequence of partial sums $\{1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, \ldots\}$
alternates between $1$ and $0$.  Since the series never converges to a limit, it is meaningless to say that

$$x = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots$$

A series must be absolutely convergent to guarantee that rearranging the terms of the series does not change the sum.

Comment: Can you rearrange the terms to change the sum? That is, to get something other than 1/2.

Comment: Of course, @mistermarko : $$1-1+1-1+\ldots\stackrel ?=(1-1)+(1-1)+\ldots=0+0+\ldots=0$$

Comment: You're assuming an infinite series has an even number of terms.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no.

0.999.. is a symbol for a rational number. So for example, $\frac{1}{3}$ is by definition the number with the property
$$ \frac{1}{3} \cdot 3 = 1,$$
and $\frac{1}{3}$ is just a symbol that we use for this number with this property. Another symbol of the same number is also
$ 0.333... $ All operations on the first proof are justified.

For the second proof $1-1+1-1 ....$ is no real number. It is not clear what you mean with this symbol, and, therefore, you can not add something to some strange symbol that has no meaning.

Comment: You're saying 0.999... is rational?

Comment: @mistermarko Yes. It is another symbol for the number 1, which is indeed rational.