# Order of operation or something I don't know?

Tags: number-theory

I am hesitant whether this question is appropriate for this forum, but I will go ahead and ask it anyways; so please bear with me.

$6$.$\bar 6$ = $20\over 3$

So if you have them multiplied by 30 ; then you should get the same numbers as the answer but obviously you do not. Why is that?

Comment: How is that equal to 20?

Comment: @Elliti123 [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-0-999999999-1) seems relevant.

Comment: Oh so you are basically saying that 6.66.....times 3 is defining a sequence that we have that sequences limit equal to 20. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is really about why is $6.\overline{6}=\frac{20}{3}$, since if you know those numbers are equal it is obvious that they multiply equally by anything.

Now,

$$6.\overline{6}= 6+ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{6}{10^i}.$$

Multiplying by $\frac{3}{20}$,

$$(\frac{3}{20})(6. \overline{6})=\frac{9}{10}+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^{i+1}}=\frac{9}{10}+\frac{1}{10}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{9}{10^i}=\frac{9}{10}+\frac{1}{10}=1.$$

Hence, $6.\overline{6}=\frac{20}{3}$.