# Does $[0.9999....]=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions, decimal-expansion

We all know that $0.99999...=1$

So does that imply $[0.99999...]=1?$

Or do we consider it as $0?$

My doubt is: any gif of the form $[0.xyz...]=0$. If $[0.99999...]=1$ won't that be contradicting?

There isn't much clear explanation in the previous post.

Here $[.]$ is the greatest integer function. I couldn't find a post containing this query on MSE. Please help :)

[Relevant Article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-0-999999999-1/116#116)

Comment: Yes, $[0.999\dots]=1$ because $0.999\dots=1$.

Comment: Since $0.999...=1$, it’s automatic that $\lfloor0.999...\rfloor=\lfloor 1\rfloor=1$.

Comment: [1] = 1, 0.999… = 1, therefore by the transitivity of equality, [0.999...] = 1. QED.

Comment: @bjb568 Actually you aren't using transitivity, but rather [Leibniz's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles).

Comment: @Wojowu but any gif of the form [0.xyz...] is considered to be equal to 0. So won't this be contradicting?

Comment: Did you link to [an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-0-999999999-1/116#116) rather than to [the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-0-999999999-1) about $0.99999999999.....=1$ on purpose, or was it a mistake?

Comment: @AdityaKumar The thing is that [0.xyz...]=0 isn't true for all x,y,z,..., and 0.999... is a sole counterexample.

Comment: @AdityaKumar Maybe you could ad you previous comment about [0.xyz.....]=0 to the post. (This could clarify what is the main point that is causing you trouble. And it could also help in deciding whether or not this is actually a duplicate of the previous question.)

Comment: Indeed $[0.99999....]=1$ shows in a certain sense that $[\cdot]$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @sinbadh: You mean "not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$". And I think this is precisely what the OP's confusion is about; it only appears to be contradition if one believes that all functions must be continuous, so that one can always interchange the order of the operations "applying the function" and "taking the limit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x = y$ then $[x] = [y]$.  How could they not?

So as $0.9999.... = 1$ it *has* to be that $[0.9999...] = [1]$.

Equality means they are the same thing.  If they are the same thing whatever you do to them will have the same result.[*]

[*](Provided what you do to them is based on their value.  It's possible for things to not be "well-defined"  which means they will not have consistent results based on circumstances that aren't about their value.  Operations that are not "well-defined" are not considered to be valid.  Usually.  There are always exceptions.)

====

Ah,  I didn't see the $[0.xyz...] = 0$ confusion.

Well, that just isn't true (although 0.9999.... is the only exception).

Well.... You have to keep in mind 0.9999.... is an integer even if it doesn't look like one.

Keep in mind math results are based on what thing *are*; not what they look like.  0.999.... is the only exception to 0.xyz.... < 1.  And it's because 0.999.... $\not <$ 1 it doesn't follow that [0.9999... ] < 1.

Believe me.  If I could apologize for the confusion, I would.

Comment: This seems to be convincing. :)

Comment: Please tell me how $1$ and $2$ are the same thing since $1/2=2/4$ and we can take numerators of both sides :)

Comment: @Wojowu I was worried you'd say something like that.  I even thought I'd bring it up but thought that just make matters worse.  There is a concept of an operation being "well-defined" which means it is defined to give consistent results.  "taking the bottom number when you write it" is not well defined.  "taking the numerator" isn't either.  But "taking the numerator of a rational number express as a ratio m/n where m/n are integers with no common factors and n is positive" is.

Comment: "Let x = 49 and y = 16 and z = 37 and so on.  Take the numbers 1 to 100 and put them in alphabetical order based on their variables" is *utterly* NOT well-defined.

Comment: .333.... does equal 1/3.  But [0.333....] = 0.

Answer (score 2):

Let's recall the definition. $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the greatest integer $n$ satisfying $n\leq x$. But now we have $1\leq 0.999\dots$, and no integer greater than $1$ doesn't satisfy $n\leq 0.999\dots$, so, from the definition, $\lfloor 0.999\dots\rfloor=1$.

What probably confuses you is the mentioned fact that $\lfloor 0.xyz\dots\rfloor=0$ for any $xyz\dots$. The problem is that this is *wrong*. It certainly doesn't follow from the definition above, though it might follow from some informal definitions (of the sort "remove everything after decimal point"). Indeed, there is precisely one counterexample to $\lfloor 0.xyz\dots\rfloor=0$, namely $0.xyz\dots=0.999\dots$.