# The representation of finite and infinite ternary's

Tags: arithmetic, decimal-expansion

In my notes I came across a sentence that says "every ternary may also be written as an infinite ternary with infinitely many trailing 3's".

I dont understand this statement, what does it mean?

Comment: So, for example, 
$$
[203.1]_4 = [203.03333...]_4
$$

Comment: I do not understand it. Every *terminating* ternary expansion may also be written as an infinite ternary with infinitely many trailing $2$'s makes sense.

Comment: You can not use the digit $3$ in ternary. Ternary only has the digits $0,1,2$. @AndréNicolas version of your statement is the correct one.

Comment: There could be translation issue.  Quaternary is the word for base four.  This is essentially the same as the whole $1=0.999999\dots$ question but in a different base.  [Read more here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-0-999999999-ldots-1).