# Is $9*(1/9) = 0.99999999...$ statement correct?

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers

We can tell that $$0.11111111... \cdot 9 = 0.999999999...$$
And that $$\frac19 = 0.11111111111...$$

Therefore
$$\frac19\cdot9 = 0.999999999...$$

However, we know that $$\frac19\cdot9 = \frac99 = 1$$

**Note**: I'm taking in account that **...** are the other rational digits left.

What am I making wrong? What is misunderstood?

Thanks for the help in clearing this problem.

Comment: There is nothing wrong: you just proved that $0.99999999... = 1$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: $.99999…$ is not irrational.  It is rational, just as $.11111…$ is rational.

Comment: The result you get to is correct, whatever the form you write it in. Making the multiplication like that for numbers with infinitely many digits is not exactly the technique I would recommend.

Comment: Similar question here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-ldots-1

Comment: Googling "0.99999 site:math.stackexchange.com" comes up with a lot of other people asking this exact question on this exact site.

Comment: @MJD Corrected it

Comment: Write down the value of $1-0.999999999999\cdots$.

Comment: As others have pointed out, there is no problem. Careful though: the statement in the title _is_ wrong, the 'dots' are important: $9 \cdot \tfrac{1}{9} = 1$ does _not_ equal $0.99999999$ (with a _finite_ number of decimals); but it is the same as $0.999\ldots$ (an _infinite_ number of 9's).

Comment: @Pichi  Wuana The decimal system is a remarkably clever way of denoting real numbers, but it does have a small confusing flaw:although each irrational number has only one representation as a decimal, there are certain fractions that can be written as decimals in two different ways. I was not crazy enough to want to be a psychiatrist, but I assure you it's comforting to figure out which fractions these are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing. What you wrote is correct, and you just proved that $0.\bar 9 = 1$

You can do the same thing with $\frac{1}{3}$ and $3$ for example:

$$1 = \frac{3}{3} = 3\cdot \frac{1}{3} = 3\cdot (0.333333\ldots) = 0.999999\ldots = 0.\bar 9$$

**Remark**

That holds only for infinite periodic decimals. You cannot, for example, state that $0.999999999999999999999999999999999 = 1$

That is not true!

Answer (score 0):

A more typical way to prove is to subtract $0.1*0.\bar 9$ from $0.\bar 9$:

$$0.\bar 9 - 0.0\bar 9 = 0.9$$

But $X - 0.1*X = 0.9*X = 0.9$ proves $X = 1$