# How to express 0.999999... recurring as a fraction without equaling 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions, fake-proofs

I was wondering is there any way to express $0.999999$ recurring as an actual fraction without equaling $1$? Because I tried to convert it into a fraction following the rules for normal recurring decimals like this:

$$\begin{align}n&=0.999\dot9\\10n&=9.999\dot9\\n&=0.999\dot9\\9n&=9\\\therefore n&=9/9\end{align}$$

But as you can see the result is $9/9$ which ultimately is equal to $1$ . And I've even tried calculating it other ways like this:

$$\begin{align}1/3&=0.333\dot3\\2/3&=0.666\dot6\\\therefore3/3&=0.999\dot9\end{align}$$

But it always ends up telling me that $0.9999999... = 1$. Is there any mistake in my logic? And I also realized this applied to other recurring decimals ending in $9$. E.g: $0.5999999...=5.4/9 = 0.6$ . So is there a way to write $0.999999...$ as a fraction so you can differentiate it from $1$?

Comment: Why do you expect to have $0.99\ldots \ne 1$?

Comment: Because they're not equal?

Comment: @Ruby: that is a common misbelief. $0.\overline{9}$ and $1$ are two representations of the same number. The decimal representation is not unique: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{9}{10^n} = 1.$$

Comment: On the other hand, if you know that $0.\overline{1}=\frac{1}{9}$ it should not come as a surprise that $$9\cdot 0.\overline{1} = 0.\overline{9} = \frac{9}{9} = 1.$$

Comment: Really? What about other recurring decimals that end in 9 like 5.999999...?

Comment: @Ruby: $5.\overline{9}=6$, simply.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-dots-1

Comment: Yeah i also tried out the 1/9  and it turned out to be equaling one so i was really keen on finding a fraction form of 0.99999.. recurring.

Comment: There is lots of good stuff about this at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999... . Btw the fact that this equality holds is not intuitive so don't feel bad if it came as a surprise. I also remember feeling uneasy about it when I first saw it.

Comment: I knew the proof a while ago but i thought it was just like a very persuadable maths trick to mess with people's brains.

Comment: The infinite decimal representation of 1: $1.0= 1.00=...=1.00000....=1$.

Comment: If they are not equal, what is a real number between them? 
"Because they are not equal" is not an argument, it is an intuition. Your intuition is wrong.

Comment: You should be pleased with yourself!  You have discovered and proved the surprising fact that $0.\dot9 = 1$.  This is how science advances.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle. Please check to make sure I haven't changed anything. For some basic information about writing math at this site see [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  Thank you for your edit .Sorry for the bad format, I'm still not very familiar with writing maths on here and I had to use a screenshot from word as i couldn't type out the recurring symbol. But I will make sure to write things in the correct format in the future!

Comment: @Ruby Haha, I'll tell you, $\LaTeX$ is way friendlier than that thing on word.  So limited and slow! Most of the symbols you will ever used can be found [here](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), and I believe you can ask how to write certain things [on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  Thanks for your help. I guess I won't be using screenshots from Word anymore... **;)**

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  Yeah, my question was kind of pointless once I found out 0.999999..=1

Comment: @Ruby You seem rather quick with comments, so I'll extend an invitation for you to entire [one of my chats](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54911/simply-beautiful-arts-realm-of-calculus-and-analysis).  I have most of the whole day to chat if you have more subtle questions related to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have proven by yourself,
$$
 0.999999999999999999999\dot9 = 1.
$$
There are no (big) logical mistakes in your post.

Because $0.99\dots$ is equal to $1$, it also cannot be another fraction.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate, more rigorous proof using series

$$ 0.9999\ldots = \frac{9}{10} + \frac{9}{10^2} + \dots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^n} $$

This is the geometric series $9\sum \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^n$, which has common ratio $r=\frac{1}{10}<1$. So using the formula for geometric series,

$$ 0.999\ldots = \frac{\frac{9}{10}}{1-\frac{1}{10}} = 1$$

Comment: Wow this seems pretty confusing....

Comment: @Ruby he's just basically saying that:$$0.9=1-0.1\\0.99=1-0.01\\0.999=1-0.001\\\vdots\\0.\overline{999}=1$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Is the line over the 9's also showing it's recurred?

Comment: @Ruby yes, the line indicates a recurring decimal

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks! Also,why can't 0.999...= 1 - 0.00000000.....1? Is there such thing as a recurring number in the middle of a decimal? **;)**

Comment: @Ruby More useful than the dot if you want something like $0.\overline{12}=0.121212\dots$

Comment: @Ruby Because$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{10^n}=0$$