# How can I convince students and teachers of my country that $0.\overline{9}=1$ and it is not approximation?

Tags: approximation, education, rational-numbers

Really i'm sorry to my failed attempt to convince my students  and also teachers of mathematics of high school of my country that $0.\overline{9}=1$ is a real equality and it is not an approximation , They described me away from the definition of integers ensemble , However I have showed them all [standards proofs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11/156150) to approach them the idea of equality but i don't succeed  . Then my question here is :

**Question:**
How   can i convince students and teachers of high school that  $0.\overline{9}=1$ and it is not approximation ?

Comment: Ask them what they propose $\,1 - 0.\overline{9}\,$ would be.

Comment: If two numbers are different $a<b$, there should be another one in between $a < \frac{a+b}{2}<b$.

Comment: @dxiv, if you say them that , you will answer this difference is non zero but closed to 0

Comment: @zeraouliarafik It's a real number, so they should be able to produce a value, not just state it's *close to 0*.

Comment: Have you tried telling them that $\frac{1}{3} = 0.\overline{3}$? From here on a childish, but pretty intuitive explanation would be that $3*\frac{1}{3} = 1 = 3 * 0.\overline{3} = 0.\overline{9}$

Comment: If they buy $\frac 13=.\overline 3$ then they should buy this.  Or, if they agree that $.\overline 9$ defines a real number $x$ then $10x=x+9$ might be convincing.

Comment: Just a thought, what about Zeno's paradox, is motion possible ? Do they agree the series converge ? What about the formula for a geometric series ?

Comment: @dxiv they may use [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant) as a counter example :)

Comment: @rtybase Don't give them such ideas ;-) I'd expect their answer would rather be something like $\,0.\overline{0}1\,$  which may be somewhat easier to argue.

Comment: @Pedro, I know all proofs of that , my question is to seek for a simple method to convince students and teachers of my country that 0.99..=1 really it is equality and dosn't approximation , I have edited the question adding some necessary thing

Comment: @zeraouliarafik Ok, I retracted the vote to close.

Comment: Its really frustrating isnt it ? I am surprised that you are having to convince math teachers of this, not a good sign. Its hard to answer such a question since we do not know the details of the situation. I can only say for myself that I try to understand as fully as possible the position of the other person, what do they think an infinite decimal is what does it represent, etc. After you understand their thinking it might be easier to formulate an effective argument.

Comment: Thanks for that , probably i missed to show them the mathematical notion of infinite decimal what does it represent , but their problems if you try to show any thing using limit for infty they w'd juge that is an approach and approximation no more

Comment: The idea here is that all the finite stages are only approximations but the infinite sum becomes exact.

Comment: @zeraouliarafik as per my first comment, ask them to find a number between $0.\overline{9}$ and $1$, change the research vector so that you won't have to convince them, but rather they will have to convince you. Offer a monetary prise eventually ...

Comment: @rtybase, What i understand in your comment that every real number present center of opned interval as the order relation of Real numbers

Comment: I was having the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ in my mind :) ... but that's not the point. The point is that they have to care about it, not you.

Comment: This might be better suited for Math Educators SE.

Comment: The mathematical content appears to be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-dots-1?noredirect=1&lq=1. The distinction with pedagogical content does not seem particularly well-fitted here. I am tempted to close this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use that : let $x=0.\bar{9}$, then
$$10x= 9.\bar9= 9+0.\bar{9}=9+x$$
so 
$$10x-9x=9$$
then
$$ 9x=9 $$
and 
$$ x=1$$
Unless they refuse basics arithmetic operations... (at list they'll have a hard time to counter-attack)

Comment: Yeah, where is the error ? Which step is wrong ?

Comment: @ReneSchipperus: you tell me ... :)

Comment: @ReneSchipperus  How do you know you can multiply both sides of your first equation by 10? The field axioms only give you a FINITE distributive law. In order to prove that you can term-by-term multiply a *convergent* infinite series, you already need to know what a convergent infinite series is ... by which time you would have no problem believing that .999... = 1. So this is at best a handwavy heuristic "proof" but not really a proof from first principles, since it assumes facts that are more sophisticated than the thing it claims to prove.

Comment: @Netchaiev "Unless they refuse basics arithmetic operations." -- What basic arithmetic operation allows you to multiply an infinite series term-by-term? If you check the field axioms you will see that there is no such operation.

Comment: @user4894 Multiplication by $10$ shifts the decimal point. A widely accepted rule.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus "Widely accepted" by people who have never seen the real number axioms and who don't understand how much work goes into properly defining the limit of an infinite series. You really don't seem to be tracking this point at all. Go ahead and look up the field axioms and in particular the distributive law. You'll see it only pertains to finite sums. It needs to be proved for infinite sums, *after you have rigorously defined the real numbers and infinite sequence and sums of real numbers*.

Comment: @user4894 And those are exactly the people OP is attempting to convince.

Comment: @user4894 : if the people we are talking about were well-taught enough in mathematics to point out the multiplication of an infinite series, they would sum this $9\times\sum 10^n$ and find out themselves in a blink that it is equal to 1.

Comment: @Netchaiev I certainly agree that the real numbers are not taught very well until one takes a course in real analysis. Prior to that, people are susceptible to thinking that there's an inherent infinitary distributive law, which of course there isn't until the proper foundation is built.

Comment: According to the edit in the question, the OP knows this proof. It seems it is not what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @user4894 Yes, indeed. My point was to provide a quick way were a non-mathematician person won't be able to find a solid counter-argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell them decimals are really just a convenient way to represent a series (after all in the decimal 0.123 we call the position of 1 the tenths place, the position of 2 the hundredths place, and so on).  Now assure them that the the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{9}{10^n} = \frac{9}{1 - 1/10} -9 = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The major underlying issues here, IMHO, are the ideas of a limit, infinity, the infinitesimal and students' intuition.

$.\overline 9  = .9 + .09 + .009 + ...$

is an infinite series whose sum ***is*** the limit of the sequence of partial sums (as was stated in your link to *standard proofs* above.  Guess you have to get them over that one, too :)

So, when describing limits to students for the first time I tell a story:

"I am standing here in this room a certain distance from the wall and I play a little game.  I will cut down the distance to myself and the wall by one-half in successive turns."

[demonstrate]

When I get very close to the wall I ask (naturally)  "Will I ever get there?" But as soon as the chorus responds a resounding: "No!" I also ask "does this wall exist?" Maybe even pounding on it a time or two.

And I go on to tell a little bit about the sometimes tragic life and times of Georg Cantor 
(The natural numbers can be placed into 1-1 correspondence with the integers (et. al.), the mathematical community's reception of transfinite arithmetic, sanitoria ...)

Or, the slope of the tangent line to a curve at a point is the limit of the slopes of the secant lines: "Does the tangent line *exist*? If I can get as close as I please to it, then I have found it."

"There are more than one encounters with infinity ..." I say, "... and *the closer you get to infinity, the close you get to madness*."

At some point, mathematical maturity has to kick in.  When I was in 8th grade I simply couldn't wrap my head around the idea that an infinite series could have a finite sum.  Xeno and I were simpatico. It took a demotion out of the honor's class and a couple of years to come around.  *Readiness* is an issue, as well.

Quoting Cauchy: "When the values successively attributed to a variable approach indefinitely to a fixed number, in a manner so as to end by differing from it *by as little as on wishes* [my italics], this last is called the limit of all the others."
-- from Dunham's *The Calculus Gallery*.

Hope some of that helped.