# Questions about 0.999... equals 1

Tags: rational-numbers, decimal-expansion, truncation-error

Being 0.999... = 1, I expect that they have the same behaviour when applying the same algorithm/operation, but:

1. If we define >, <, =, as checking digit by digit two number, we have that 0 < 1 in the first check and an algorithm will say 0.999... < 1
2. If we truncate both numbers at any point (let's say 3 decimal digits), we have 0.999 vs 1.

Why I am wrong? Can someone help me to clarify?

Thank you in advance from this junior amateur noob! :)

> Please, note that I'm aware of
>   [Is it true that $0.999999999\dots=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-dots-1)
>   but I wanted to know why truncating and comparison as explained in
>   school are wrong when dealing with 0.9999...

Comment: What is your exact algorithm that says $0.999\cdots < 1$?

Comment: It is just an mental algorithm, like I was told when I was a kid: "you start comparing the first digit, if there are equal, keep going, if the one on the left is largest, you have >, otherwise, you have <. Just remembering my old days of school. Maybe "algorithm" is too much a big word for that... Sorry the misunderstanding!

Comment: The algorithm (in particular, the first point) would never finish ...

Comment: Even as in the fashion I explain in my comment? Why?

Comment: Think of it this way: If $0.999\cdots < 1$, then you should be able to find another real number, say $x$ such that $0.999\cdots < x < 1$. Also, that "algorithm" is used only when we are starting to learn mathematics. Once you learn series, you can understand why $0.999\cdots = 1$ and our algorithm fails!

Comment: @JonnyCrunch You could of course define such an algorithm, but it would not produce the correct answer. That's because $0.999\ldots = 1$.

Comment: You may be interested in reading the related MSE question, & $26$ answers!, at [Is it true that $0.999999999\dots=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-dots-1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it true that $0.999999999\dots=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-dots-1)

Comment: *expect that they have the same behaviour when applying the same algorithm/operation* --- Note that 1/4 = 2/8, but if I apply "the algorithm" that consists of deleting the first two characters, then we get 4 = 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that if we truncate both numbers at any finite point, $0.\overline{9}$ will compare less than 1. But by analogy, consider the following two programs:

```
i = 0
while true:
    print i
    print i+1
    i <- i + 2
```

and

```
i = 0
while true:
    print i
    i <- i + 1
```

Those two programs will print out exactly the same numbers - but at any given iteration, the first one will have printed out twice as many numbers. Any finite truncation of the first process will "look much bigger" than the corresponding finite truncation of the second process; and yet their output "at infinity" is the same.

You need to "look at the whole process" to determine equality.

---

By the way, equality of arbitrary reals is undecidable. So your algorithm never stood a chance of being a general way of comparing arbitrary reals.

Comment: Ok, I have been thinking about all the output you all gave me. For sure, 0.999... = 1 and I was wrong because I was confusing the number (the unit) with the way of "painting" the number (0.999... or 1). It is like (Magritte style) I have a pipe red (0.999...) and another blue  (1) and I said the they both cannot be pipes at the same time becuase one is red and the other blue. I am wrong because I am looking to an accident: the color. In my case, colors are truncate and the "algorithm", they look at how we write the number, not to the number. It is something like this??

Comment: Yep, something like that - there are two ways to express the number, but they are the same number.