# Approximation of dividing odd number

Tags: limits

I am not a mathematician but I have a question.

I found

- $1  / 3 = 0.33333....$
- $2 / 3 = 0.666666...$
- $3 / 3 = 1$ while it should be $0.999999....$

Same as dividing by $9$

- $1/9=0.11111..$
- $2/9= 0.2222..$
- $3/9=0.3333..$
- $9/9=1$ while it should be $0.99999..$

Divided by $7$ is little bit different. As

- $1/7= 0.142857 \, 142857 \, 142857$
- $2/7= 0.285714 \, 285714\, 285714$
- $3/7= 0.428571\, 428571\, 428571$

The same pattern of number repeated in the same arrangement. But with $7/7$ the answer is $1$

I can understand the approximation but with the number increases the error increased.

To explain it:

```
                        Should be
1/3=0.3333.            1/3=0.3333
2/3=0.6666.            2/3=0.6666
3/3=1.                 3/3=0.9999
4/3=1.333.             4/3=1.2222
5/3=1.666.             5/3=1.55555
6/3=2                  6/3=1.88888
```

Explanation is appreciated

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-dots-1

Comment: Uhm... Provided that *there is no such thing as digit-by-digit operations* for numbers with an infintite decimal expansion, what makes you assume that $0.\overline 9\times 2=1.\overline 8$? In my book, for instance, $0.9999\times 2=1.9998$.

Comment: Also, $142857\cdot 7=999999$, so by your (incorrect) idea, $\frac{7}{7}=0.\dot{9}$ too.

Comment: You forgot to include the carries.

Answer (score 2):

$$0.9999999...=\frac{9}{10}(1+\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{10^2}+.....)=\frac{9}{10}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{10}}=1$$

Answer (score 0):

There is a *bijection* between infinite ultimately periodic decimal expansions and rational numbers, *except* when the period consists only of the digit $9$. In this case,, one proves that deleting the final $9$s and replacing last digit $d\ne 9$ with the digit $d+1$ defines a decimal number which is equal to the given infinite decimal expansion.