# Confusing concerning the nature of $1=0.999...?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let that

$\frac{1}{3}=0.333...$, then multiply by $3$:

$\frac{1}{3}\times 3=1\tag1$

$0.333...\times3=0.999...\tag2$

$1-0.999...=0.000...0001$

Here it seems that $1 \ne 0.999...$

So what is the correct view concerning $1$ and $0.999...$

Are they equal or not ?

Comment: $0.000\ldots0001$? What?

Comment: Are you sure $1-0.999... = 0.000...1$ ?? How many $0$ are there??

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-dots-1

Comment: $1 - 0.999... = 1 - \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} 9\cdot 10^{-i} = 1 - 1 = 0.$

Comment: Do you already know what a sequence and its limit is? If not, it is hard to really explain why $0.9999999\ldots =1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can prove there exists a correspondence between real numbers and infinite decimal expansions. In this correspondence, rational numbers correspond to *ultimately periodic* infinite decimal expansions. The correspondence is bijective, *except for decimal numbers*, which correspond either to infinite decimal expansions which end in an infinity of $9$s (period $1$), or to the more usual form, obtained from the previous one as follows: that last digit $d<9$ is replaced with the digit $d+1$, and the following $9$s are replaced with $0$s. Of course, usually, one does not write the final $0$s.