# floor function of $5.999\dots$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

What is $\left\lfloor5.\overline9\right\rfloor$ where $\lfloor.\rfloor$ denotes the floor function?

I believe it to be $6$ since converting $5.\overline9$ to fractional form yields $6$. Meanwhile my friend insists that $\left\lfloor5.\overline9\right\rfloor = 5$ since actually $5.\overline9 \ne 6$ but rather is closer to $6$ than any other real number.

Is $\left\lfloor5.\overline9\right\rfloor$ $6$ or $5$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You are correct.  $5.\overline9=6$

Comment: Actually $5.\bar 9$ is exactly $6$ , not just close to $6$ , so the floor-function of $5.\bar 9$ is $6$ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct.

Actually $5.\overline9=6$ (cf. [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-dots-1)),

so $\lfloor5.\overline9\rfloor=\lfloor6\rfloor=6$.