# Problem regarding a MST proof of 0.99999...=1

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation, real-numbers, decimal-expansion, number-systems

I came across an answer of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-dots-1/87#87) (which is the highest voted, and also awarded bounties worth 50 reputations).
To quote, this is what the answer said:-

"Suppose this was not the case, i.e. $0.9999... \neq 1$. Then $0.9999... < 1$ (I hope we agree on that). But between two distinct real numbers, there's always another one (say $x$) in between, hence $0.9999... < x < 1$.

The decimal representation of $x$ must have a digit somewhere that is not $9$ (otherwise $x = 0.9999...$). But that means it's actually smaller, $x < 0.9999...$, contradicting the definition of $x$.

Thus, the assumption that there's a number between $0.9999...$ and $1$ is false, hence they're equal."

I have a problem regarding this, it merely tells that there exists no $x$ such that $$0.999...<x<1$$ and thus reaches the conclusion that $$0.9999...=x$$ What am I missing?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119467/discussion-on-question-by-eisenstein-problem-regarding-a-mst-proof-of-0-99999).

Answer (score 4):

There *is* a problem with this proof, but it's not where you're looking for it. Its logic is supposed to be: assume both numbers are different, then, there must be a number strictly between them ("...between two distinct real numbers, there's always another one..."), and that leads to a contradiction. The way the contradiction is reached is faulty, though: "*The* decimal representation of $x$ must have ..." is implicitly assuming that there *is* a unique decimal representation of $x$, while proving that $0.9999\ldots=1.0000\ldots$, i.e. that decimal representation is *not* always unique. A proof proving its own invalidity is a rare specimen.