# question about flooring a certain kind of numbers

Tags: limits, proof-writing, ceiling-and-floor-functions, theorem-provers

Our math teacher was teaching us about the floor function and after finishing all the important parts we started to do some exercises by ourselves and there was this problem which we all did wrong:
$$\lfloor2.\overline{9}\rfloor=??$$
We all thought that since $2.\overline{9}< 3$ the answer would be $2$, but the teacher said the answer is $3.$ He tried to explain us that since we can't find any number between $2.\overline{9}$ and $3$ it can be mathematically proved that $2.\overline{9} = 3.$

He said the full proof of that is very hard and long so I am curious about this subject and I want to know the reason behind this.

thanks in advance

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11/1508), which has 89 (!) answers.

Comment: The proof is **not** very hard or long. It is immediate if you have an understanding of limits, and well-explainable if you accept this argument: $x=2.\overline{9},10x-x=27,9x=27\implies x=3$. This works because a decimal string such as $2.\overline{9}$ must converge to a real number