# Upper Bound Question

Tags: calculus, upper-lower-bounds

I am currently going through Apostol's Calculus Book. Apostol is explaining the upper bound axiom. In example 3, it is stated that the set does not contain a Maximum bur rather only bounded above. My Question is why is 0.999999999999999 not the upper bound making it also the Maximum element ? [image: Upper Bound example]

Comment: $0.999999999999999 <1$

Comment: do you mean [0.999...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...)? It equals to 1 exactly but it is not in the sequence set.

Comment: Also, for a proof, say $x$ is any number the set. Then $x<\frac{x+1}2<1$, showing that you can always find a bigger number in the set, so there can be no maximal number.

Comment: @auntyellow Yes that's exactly what I meant. I did not know what it would be equal to exactly one until Adrian and yourself pointed out now. But now that I know this I guess the example makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters: $0.999999…<1$ as pointed out by @geetha290krm.

Now, the interval $I=[0,1)$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}$: all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $0\leq x <1$. Note that $1$ is an upper bound of the interval (a number that is larger that the biggest number of the set). For example: $2$, $\pi$, $2022$ and $10^{10}$ are all upper bounds of $I$ since each of those real numbers are less than $1$.

The *supremum* of an interval is the smallest upper bound of a (upper) bounded set. If the supremum of the set is in the set itself, then the supremum is called *the maximum element* of the set. For example, in the interval $J=[0,1]$ has $1$ as its maximum element; in $I$, the supremum is also $1$, but since $1 \notin I$ then $1$ is not the maximum element.

Also, $0.999999999999999$ is not an upper bound since $0.999999999999999<1$. You can put as many $9$’s as you like and it still wouldn’t an upper bound of $I$, since $0.999999999999999…9<1$.

The only way is to put an **infinite** number of $9$‘s, since $0.\overline{9}=1$.

Comment: Hi, Adrian, First thank you for the answer. However, I am still a bit confused because why can't 0.999 with infinite number of 9's be the upper bound. Furthermore I don't understand how 0.99 with infinite 9's would equal 1.

Comment: The proof is not easy. Some answers from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-ldots-1) may not be strict. Please refer to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...#Analytic_proofs) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...#Proofs_from_the_construction_of_the_real_numbers), and need some knowledge about real analysis.