# How can 1 = 0.9999999...?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am new to proofs, and I am trying to prepare for my discrete mathematics course that I will take next semester. The professor made videos in the past (corona-seasons) and he told us to do this proof on our own.

$$1 = 0.\bar{9}$$

Can anyone help me with this please? I've seen this in my textbook since grade 4 but I could never understand smh.

Comment: Welcome to Math S.E.  Do you know the formula for the sum of a geometric series $0.9+0.09+0.009+\dots$?

Comment: If needed, there are many proofs here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-ldots-1

Comment: Call it $x$ and multiply by 10

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! The proof that helped me was multiplying it by ten then distributing, subtracting 0.99... on both sides, then dividing it by  at the end.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner That would be $$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} \frac{9}{10^i}$$

Comment: So $0.999\dots=0.9+0.09+0.009\dots=\dfrac {0.9}{1-0.1}=1$

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to prove it.
You could use the geometric sum, which needs some analytic knowledge.
Without this, you could do the following:
$$
\begin{align}
x &= 0.\overline{9} &|\cdot 10\\
10\cdot x&=9.\overline{9} &| -x\\
9\cdot x &=9 &|\text{since $x = 0.\overline{9}$} \\
x &= 1
\end{align}
$$