# In an infinite sum, is there an actual term at an infinite position?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

The sum of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n  = 1,  
$$
*exactly*.

It has been proved that the sum does not just tend to 1 and that it is not just defined as 1, but rather, it is *exactly* 1.

How do we explain the value of n needed in order to bring the final summation to *exactly* 1?

(I say "final summation" because something had to add together to give a final sum of 1 *exactly*.)

I know "final summation" goes against current theories, and I also cannot not find a good answer to this problem without using an infinitely large n, or something else to make it make sense.

So does n have to equal infinity?  If not, what is the alternative?

Comment: There is no final $n$ but with all the positive integers the sum is indeed exactly $1$

Comment: When you study calculus, you will learn about "convergence".

Comment: It's just semantics.  The infinite series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}$ is defined as the limit $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N 2^{-n}$.  The sequence $\sum_{n=1}^N 2^{-n}$ approaches but doesn't equal $1$.  The limit $\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N 2^{-n}$ exactly equals $1$.  The function/sequence approaches the limit, but the limit exactly equals its own value.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as the standard question about $0.999\dots = 1$  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-true-that-0-999999999-ldots-1).

Comment: @BrianMoehring, I agree with your math. But the expression “it’s just semantics” always rubs me very much the wrong way. Semantics is nothing less than the study of meaning (in the context of language), so if one dismisses some feature of an utterance as semantics—particularly in an offhand manner—what can remain to that utterance that matters in the least? I imagine a physician would react much the same way on hearing someone say of some drug, “Oh never mind that characteristic, it’s just therapeutics.”

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum If you want, replace  "It's just semantics" with "The issue you're having isn't mathematical but rather a function of misunderstanding what we mean when we say those words."  To me, _it's just pragmatics_.

Comment: @BrianMoehring - I think what Paul Tanenbaum is saying is that understanding what the symbols being manipulated mean (the concepts, the relationships, the behaviors) *is* mathematics, or is at least close to the very core of it, so in this sense "the issue [...] isn't mathematical" doesn't quite work either - unless by that you mean to say that the issue isn't that there is some crucial flaw in the already established mathematical notions and the underlying mathematical theory.

Comment: Studentian, I think what possibly confuses you is the use of the term "sum" to describe the expression $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$.  In fact, it is not literally a sum: see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4809680/72694).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović The soundness of your analysis wholly depends on the one with whom you're having the discussion.  My assumption has been and continues to be that OP is a _platonist_ or at least some near-approximation of one.  For such a person, the types of explanations given here will be woefully insufficient even when they're correct, because we've misidentified the semantics.  As for Paul, he has seemingly assumed my statement of "it's just semantics" was used as an often-dismissive argument rather than the thesis of my comment.  My response to him, admittedly, was a little flippant.

Comment: @BrianMoehring - Fair enough. While knowing if the OP leans towards this or that philosophical doctrine is useful in formulating an answer, and picking a certain POV, I don't know that it is *that* useful. Also, why assume when you can ask? To me it looks like what would actually help the OP is expanding their understanding of what equality means, followed by a clear explanation of what's meant by a sum of an infinite series;  as far as I'm concerned, the goal is to have them understand the concepts, they don't have to philosophically like them - that's a whole other discussion.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović HI, I am still trying to resolve this issue.  Some people say that the sum equals exactly 1, and some say that it gets "close enough" to equal exactly 1.  I am confused by the former answer because no n is big enough for the sum to equal exactly 1.  The latter response confuses me because I wonder how close to 1 can also equal exactly 1.  "Close" in that context is not a value other than 1.  Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: You use $n$ in the expression of $\sum_{\color{red}{n}=1}^\infty \frac 1{2^{\color{red}{n}}}$ but later talk about an $n$ to set the summation to $1$.  Um, are you aware that the $\color{red}{n}$ in your notation is not a value ever set or relelvant to the final value?  That is is merely a notation for an index?  That the $\color{red}{n}$ refers to $\frac 1{2^{\color{red}1}} + \frac 1{2^{\color{red}2}} + \frac 1{2^{\color{red}3}}+ ....$?  There *isn't* any actual value of $\color{red}{n}$.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I meant the input needed (n in this case) to arrive at the summed value of 1.  Supposedly the sum reaches 1 but there is no value of n for this to be possible unless if the value of n is infinity itself.

Comment: We can not figure out what $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^k}$ is by actually adding up all the infinite terms because there are an infinite number of the terms and there is no final term where we can say "that's it; I'm done".  We can only know what the sum is by knowing that A)  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^k} > \sum_{k=1}^N\frac 1{2^k}$ for every possible $N$.  *EVERY* *POSSIBLE* $N$.  and by knowing B) That $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^k}$ is the *smallest* such possible real number.  So $\sum_{k=1}^{infty}\frac 1{2^k}$ is the smallest number that is bigger than $\frac 12,\frac 34.. etc..$

Comment: No.. the sum does *NOT* "reach" $1$.  To reach $1$ it has to get to $1$ and then... stop.  The sum never stops.  But it goes *past* every number *less* than $1$.  As the sum goes *past* every number less than $1$ but no further, its value is exactly $1$.  You don't have to "reach" something to be equal to something.... But it is wrong and meaningless to look at the sum part way and say "it has only gotten to...".  A sum is the *total* sum.  It is not any of its smaller parts.

Comment: @fleablood Well this is absolutely fascinating.  It is also something nobody has mentioned to me in this endeavor of mine (to fully understand what is going on here).  However, one of the things I have learnt (or at least think I have learnt) is that the geometric proofs seem to actually reach 1.  Are they not actually reaching 1?  Are they exactly accurate?

Comment: "reach" is an english language word refering to a movement of a body or a being.  What can it mean in mathematics?  If you visualize all the *partial* steps of $\frac 12 + \frac 14 + \frac 18 +... $ and visualize them as lights on a number line you well see an infinite number of lights imediately clustered around $1$.  But a) $1$ itself is not lit and b) there is no "final" or complete last step of the sum.  So what does "sum" in this case mean.  What *IS* the sum? Most (but not all) mathematicians take it to mean the *value* associated is that limit: $1$. Clustering about *is* the def.

Comment: @fleeblood Okay thanks for that.  I feel like I am getting closer to finally being at peace with this.  But now I wonder what the sum is geometrically.  If 1 is not included in the sum, wouldn't the geometrical representation be a half-open line segment that includes 0 but not 1?

Comment: @fleablood hello, I have been thinking a lot about what you said about the final sum existing somewhere between every number (I assume all reals) and 1.  But now I just see the problem returning.  The problem being that we still have to deal with an infinite n.  The end expression/s seem to vanish to 0 as it enters the "void"; I say this because any finite value would put the sum greater that 1.  Doesn't this mean that n had to reach infinity?

Comment: What do you mean by "final sum" "between every number and 1"  "deal with" "infinite n" "end expression" "vanish to $0$" "enter the 'void'" "any finite value (finite value of *what*?)" "put the sum".  "Doesn't this mean... (doesn't *what* mean)". "n reach infinity".  I honestly have zero idea what you mean by any of these phrases and I don't know what you are asking.... The is no number $n$.  You refer to the *FIRST* value as $\frac 12$ and then $327$th value as $\frac 1{2^{327}}$ and so on.  You add an *infinite* number of these terms and the infinite sum is $1$.  The is no final term.

Comment: @fleablood Sorry, I should have reminded you about what part of the discussion we had before.  You had said, "No.. the sum does NOT "reach" 1. To reach 1
 it has to get to 1 and then... stop. The sum never stops. But it goes past every number less than 1".  I understand this to mean that the sum is somewhere between every number less than 1 and 1.  Then I suppose it gets "rounded" off to 1.  This comment was very interesting to me, and I have thought about it quite a bit.  ...

Comment: @fleablood ... However, my original issue persists about what n would have to be to equal to reach this area between numbers and 1, "void" (I don't know the correct term).  At first, I thought it solved my issue, but now I think that n would still have to be infinite to enter this void

Comment: The sum $\sum_{n=1}^M a_n$ means you go up to $M$.  That is the number of terms you have to do.  In that expression there is *no* number $n$.  $n$ is just a indexing place holder.  It is the $M$ that tells you the range of the index.  The index spans from $1$ to $M$.  The sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ means that there is no $n$.  $n$ is just an index.  And the $\infty$ tells you the index spans all the natural numbers and there is no end or final point.  $n$. DOES. NOT. GO. TO. ANYTHING!!!!!!!!!  $n$ spans the the entire range of natural numbers.  THere is !!!!!!!***NO***!!!!!!!! final term.

Comment: @fleablood yes, it has sunk in for me now that the sum does not stop.  I was just asking how you think terms that are indexed by the natural numbers enter this "void".  It doesn't seem possible that the terms can enter this void having been indexed by something less than infinity.

Comment: There is no void and nothing enters it and nothing less than infinity is indexed.  You have an infinite number of things each of which is finite.  That is a basic necessary mathematical fact. One *must* have an infinite number of things that are each finite. There is nothing contradictory or paradoxical about it and *any* naive misconception of trying to count to infinity or that you will run out of finiteness will *ALWAYS* lead to nonsensical contradiction.

Comment: Think of a inch long line segment.  There are an infinite number of point on the line and every one of them is a finite value.  That is how it *HAS* to be.  It's not weird.  It's not mystical it's how it must be.  There are an infinite amount of natural numbers.  Each on is finite.  THat is how it *must* be.  There is *NOTHING* mystical about it.  That is all.

Comment: @fleablood thanks for your patience with me.  I am interested to know more about the place between all numbers less than 1 and 1.  If I understood you correctly, the sum exists somewhere in there (not the final sum since there is no final sum).  For this sum to continue in this "void" it would seem to me that the terms have become 0.  I say this because if there were a term in the void greater than 1, then the sum would actually be greater than 1, and that can't happen.

Comment: @fleablood ... and the problem that I have with the terms becoming 0 is that they would have to become 1/n^infinity, wouldn't they?

Comment: The terms do not "become" anything.  They *are* each a $\frac 1{2^k}$. They never "change" to anything else.  (And none of them are $0$).  It is true that ones with high indexes are smaller than ones with low indexes, and that we can find an infinite number of them as close to $0$ as we'd like by looking at those with high enough indexes. but they never "become" anything.  And $\frac 1{2^{\infty}}$ is not a number.  There is not such thing as $\frac 1{2^\infty}$.

Comment: When people say "they approach $0$" they are being lazy and incorrect.  What they actually mean is: For any distance $\epsilon > 0$, no matter how small, then for all $k$ high enough (in practicality, for all $n > \log_2 \frac 1{\epsilon}$) we can have $\frac 1{2^k} < \epsilon$.  *Colloquially* we say (but it's lazy and no accurate) that we can "make" $\frac 1{2^k}$ as close to zero as we like but... we probably shouldn't say that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150774/discussion-between-studentician-and-fleablood).

Answer (score 21):

You ask, among other things, if $n$ has to equal infinity. In fact, $n$ **cannot** equal infinity. What $n$ does do is take on more and more values—every one of which is finite—without end. Infinity is not a number in anything like the way that 2 and 17 and 53126908 are.

You also say that “It has been proved that $n$ [here I’m sure you mean not $n$ but the infinite series] does not just tend to 1 and that it is not just defined as 1, but rather, it is exactly 1.” That is not so. One can’t prove anything about any infinite series until one has defined what “infinite series” is going to mean. What shall we mean in speaking of a sum of an unbounded number of terms?

That definition—which mathematicians have **chosen**—is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = \lim_{N \to \infty}{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n},$$
provided that the specified limit exists.
In our case, that limit does exist.
Consider that when $N=3$, the sum is
$$1/2+1/4+1/8 = 7/8 = 1-1/8,$$
and when $N=4$, the sum is
$$1/2+1/4+1/8+1/{16} = 15/16 = 1 - 1/{16}.$$
I think you can see that in general, the sum for any $N$ is $1-1/{2^N}$. So we can guarantee that the difference between our sum and 1 is smaller than whatever positive threshold we wish, no matter how tiny, simply by adding up enough terms, in other words by choosing $N$ large enough.
And **that’s** what we mean when we say that the limit exists and equals 1.

That argument is our basis—but it’s also our only basis—for saying that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} = 1$. And it makes sense only because of how we have **chosen** to **define** infinite series, or what you might casually describe as “summing from 1 to infinity.”

Comment: Does it actually equal 1 or is it just defined to equal 1?

Comment: @Studentician: There is no distinction between "actually" and "defined" in mathematics. It actually equals one because it is defined to equal one. If you want to use a different definition, you can do that, but you should probably choose a different notation, to avoid confusing people.

Comment: @Studentician It isn't that the infinite sum is "defined to equal 1". What is "defined" is that an infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ *means* the limit as $N\to\infty$ of the sequence  $s_N=\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$ of finite sums, if that limit exists. In the case you give where $a_n=(1/2)^n$, you can show that the limit does exist, and equals $1$.

Answer (score 10):

The alternative you seek is the very  *definition*  of what that infinite sum means.
There is no

> value of $n$ [that] bring[s] the final summation to exactly $1$.

The infinite sum is *defined* to be $1$ because you can make the finite start as *close* to $1$ as you like if you use *enough*
terms. In particular, you can check that the sum of the first $n$ terms is $1-1/2^n$ so when $m > n$ the sum of the first $m$ terms is within $1/2^n$ of $1$.

Comment: That is what I have learnt, but it doesn't make any sense to me.  There is no natural number that makes the sum 1.

Comment: @Studentician But likewise there's no number less than 1 that the sum does not eventually exceed.

Comment: But for every succession, there will be a gap (value greater than 0) that follows.

Comment: @Studentician Sorry this definition makes no sense to you (now). It turns out to be a very _useful_ way to work with infinite sums. If you go on to study more mathematics you will become more comfortable with limits like this.

Comment: I have spent many years trying to connect this series from 0 to 1.  I do understand the concepts that have been mentioned.  Actually, I was hoping to read a response to what I said to @Kyle here in the comment section about the gap comment.  I want to read a good reason how this gap closes.

Comment: @Studentician What gap? Any gap you name will contain elements of the set of partial sums, no matter how small you make the gap. But, as soon as the gap shrinks to 0, this is no longer true and since we *must* shrink the gap to 0 at a value of 1 and only 1, that is why we say the limit is equal to 1.

Comment: @Kyle there is always a gap between any two rational numbers.  In this case it would be any rational number 1/2^n and 1.

Comment: @Studentician I assume you mean between 1 - 1/2^n and 1, but in any case 1/2^n isn't a number, it's more of a function that maps the naturals to a particular sequence of rationals. Sure, if you arbitrarily pick any one of them it will have some non-zero difference from 1, but if you're going to do that, why not say the sum is 1/2 or 3/4? We want to assign one and only one value to this sum, not many and not an arbitrary one.

Comment: @Studentician "there is no natural number that makes the sum 1". Yes, exactly, that's why we use ∞. There is no natural number that equals ∞. Infinity is a process, not a number.

Comment: @Studentician Do you know the definition of real numbers in terms of the least upper bound property and (maybe) the derivation of the real numbers by Deidekind cuts.  (Well, the latter is not important) but the former is VITAL.  If you take a set such as $[1,2)$ or $[1\frac 12, \pi)$ or a set $\{\frac 12, \frac 34, \frac 78, \frac {15}{16}.........\}$ those sets do not have a greatest element.  But they *DO* have a least upper bound. That is $2$ or $\pi$ or $1$ is a number that is at least as big as them but is the *smallest* number that is at least as big as them. That is *VITAL* ......

Comment: ... it is vital because for every real number $w$, rational or irrational, we can find (infinitely) many sets where $w$ *is* the least upper bound of the set.  And this is vital because this might be the only way to express the values of some real numbers (for example for some irrational numbers). Through this the infinite set $\{\frac 12, \frac 34,\frac 78, ... etc....\}$ has exactly *one* and only *one* LEAST UPPER BOUND and that is *NOT* any of the actual sums. It is the *INFINITE* sum. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2^k}$ is *not* a sum to any $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{2^k}$. It is ....

Comment: @Studentician .... it is the *infinite* sum which is the least upper bound of the set of all such sums.

Answer (score 3):

Pay attention to the summation boundaries:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} &=& k \\
\frac{k}{2} &=& \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} \\
&=& \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{\infty+1}}\\
&=& \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{16} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^{\infty}}\\
&=& \sum_{n=2}^\infty 2^{-n} \\
&=&  \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} - \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{k}{2} &=& k - \frac{1}{2} \\
k &=& 1 \\
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}$$

Supposing you wanted to do mindless addition instead of relying on the perfectly sensible algebraic solution, your error will be the size of your last included term. For example, including 2 terms, $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$, leaves the sum $\frac{1}{4}$ away from the correct answer. Which is a roundabout way of saying that $n$ must get to infinity because if it doesn't, you have an error of $2^{-n}$.

EDIT:

Per the comments, I should definitely have proven that the series converges. There are a lot of complicated methods for that, but this picture does a good enough job. The boundary of the box is $1$ which means it has an area of $1$; it converges. As for what infinite summation means ... Zeno's first paradox maps to this very problem. Infinite summation shows how an infinite number of terms can sometimes add up to a finite number.

[image: summation of 1/2^n]

Edit 2:

Per a long conversation in the comments, we found that a misunderstanding about the set of natural numbers is at the heart of the confusion. The set of natural numbers, **$\mathbb N$, has an infinite number of elements** because for $n$ in $\mathbb N$, $n+1 = m$ defines a new natural number $m$. Despite this, $\infty$ is not usually defined to be an element of this set because we can't do arithmetic on it in the same way: $n \cdot m = l$ where $l = n$ iff $m = 1$, whereas $\infty \cdot x = \infty$ for $ x > 0$, etc... The "final" term, $\frac{1}{2^\infty}$, evaluates with a straightforward limit to $0$. In essence, the confusion stemmed from the opacity of $\infty$ within these axioms.

Comment: This trick is good if you want to remember how to get the value of the limit. However it does not answer the current question as it supposes that you know what this "infinite summation" is and that the series converges, which is what the question is about. Then one can indeed apply the arithmetic laws for absolutely convergent series.

Comment: The "perfectly sensible" algebraic solution works here, but the idea in general is very easy to misuse (or abuse) if you haven't carefully considered the convergence of the series.

Comment: @LutzLehmann better?

Comment: @JuliaHayward better?

Comment: Yes, it is better, and I would not know how to improve it without turning it into a copy of another answer, Paul Tanenbaums for example. But you are still somewhat light on the "philosophical" question, how an expression becomes even more symbolic than usual when an infinity symbol occurs in it.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I take issue with that particular answer. In many cases, arbitrarily close to $\infty$ is the only sensible path, but here, I see no reason for a limit - only that $\infty + 1 = \infty$. Zeno's paradox really comes at it from the other side - this converges and I know what it converges to, but how can it take infinitely many steps? As for what OP is asking, I've deleted a section explaining how many summands a calculator needs twice because calculators are smart and varied enough for it to be a hard answer; there are many ways to interpret things.

Comment: In elementary calculus, $\infty$ is a symbol that indicates that something different is happening here, but is not an integer or a real number. How exactly do you get "close" to infinity? However far you go, you are still an infinity away from infinity. Your equation has no sense in the current context. If you change to non-standard analysis, you can argue with i-large or unlimited integers like M. Katz does in his answer. But they still are not infinite, just non-standard, inaccessible.

Comment: @user121330 I should have responded to this post before.  The reason why I didn't is because I didn't feel it directly answered my issue.  My issue is that the only way that the sum can get to 1 is if there is an n that can correlate to a term that will bring the sum to exactly 1.  But there is no natural number large enough that can do this.

Comment: New natural numbers can be found by incrementing while $\infty + 1 = \infty$. Asking for a natural number big enough to be $\infty$ is like asking for a coffee without water or a rainbow without yellow. To answer your implicit question, you can stop the summation at any time and just add in the last term again if you want, but then, it's no longer an infinite series.

Comment: @user121330 then if no natural number can bring the sum to exactly 1, how can we justify having a point at 1 at the end of the summation?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Good day, I was looking back at all of the replies here in the comments because I still don't feel that my issue has been resolved.  I notice you made a comment here for me.  As I understand it, the summation ends with a point at 1 exactly.  If no nth sum can put that point there, it seems like it shouldn't be there.  Isn't this an implication?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking how a function (the summation) could map a number from a domain which includes $\infty$ to one which is just the naturals. Is that right? To this, I would say $-(2i)^2$ maps from complex, $(\sqrt{2})^4$ maps from reals and $16\cdot \frac{1}{4}$ maps from rational to 4, a positive integer. Perhaps you can explain what the area of the box is if it isn't 1? Or what the summation is if it isn't 1?

Comment: @user121330 My issue is more about the n required to give a total value of 1.  If n is held to only finite numbers, the series will never reach 1.  If n = infinity (which I know is not allowed), that would be exactly what we need.   But with n just being finite, I don't see how a sum indexed by n will ever bring the sum to exactly 1.

Comment: And we are back at the start. A sum with an infinite number of terms does not exist in arithmetic. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ is an object of calculus, which in the main part is limits. The sequence of partial sums was mentioned multiple times. In the other direction, for any convergent sequence one can write $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=a_0+\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n-a_{n-1})$. With that your conceptual problem is generalized. The question now is, do you want to do calculus/analysis or do you stay with algebra?

Comment: Why isn't $\infty$ allowed?

Comment: It sorta seems like you've built yourself a nifty pair of handcuffs and can't figure out why things don't work right when you're wearing them.

Comment: @user121330 I think we are suppose to move to a chat, but I am not sure how.  The reason why I said that infinity is not allowed is because if the index equals infinity, then there has to be a term of 1/2^(infinity).   This seems to imply that an infinite number of terms, the natural numbers in particular, has to have an infinite number among them.  Isn't this the reason we always put "goes to infinity" instead of just infinity at the top of the sigma symbol?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I am not sure what the algebra side says about this.  This is new information to me that I am MOST happy to receieve.

Comment: The set of natural numbers, $\mathbb{N}$, has $\infty$ members, but doesn't include $\infty$ because, for example, $\infty\cdot x = \infty$ for all $x > 0$. Another example - the one that proves that $\mathbb{N}$ has $\infty$ members is that for any $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$, $n+1$ is a new member (which $\infty$ similarly fails).

Comment: @user121330 I don't understand why infinity*x for x>0 means that infinity can't be in the set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150071/discussion-between-user121330-and-studentician).

Answer (score 1):

Others have tried to answer your direct question, but based on your interactions here, I believe your confusion is actually about what a limit is and how it works, so I will try to answer that instead.

A limit of a sequence of numbers $s = (s_0, s_1, s_2, ...)$, if it exists, is a number such that eventually (starting from far enough in the sequence), all elements of the sequence are arbitrarily close to $\mathsf{limit}(s)$.

To make the above a bit more mathematically precise: a number $n_{lim}$ is a limit of a sequence $s$ if and only if for an *arbitrary* error bound $\epsilon$, all numbers of the sequence but those from some finite inital portion of it are within the interval

$$(n_{lim} - \epsilon, n_{lim} + \epsilon)\,.$$

Notice that the limit itself *needs **not** ever be present in the sequence itself*! It is sufficient that the sequence gets "closer and closer". For example, the limit of $(0, 0.3, 0.33, 0.333, ...)$ is $1/3$, despite that $1/3$ is not an element of the sequence.

Also notice that taking the limit is *not* a process that computes someting / eventually spits out some number. (Even though you can intuitively think of it in such way, if you *prefer*.) A limit is simply a number which satisfies the above formal definition.<sup>0</sup>

---

Now back to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = 1\,.$$

In math,

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dots$$

is defined as

$$\mathsf{limit}(\sum_{n=1}^0\dots,\sum_{n=1}^1\dots,\sum_{n=1}^2\dots, \dots)\,.$$

That is, we're *defining* how to perform an infinite summation by trying to find out which number we're approaching as we sum more and more terms. Again, the result needs not appear at any finite "stage" of the "process", it just needs to get "closer and closer".

So we have

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n &= \mathsf{limit}(
\sum_{n=1}^0 0.5^n,
\sum_{n=1}^1 0.5^n,
\sum_{n=1}^2 0.5^n,
\dots)\\
&= \mathsf{limit}(0, 0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.875, ...)\,.
\end{align*}$$

Now take any arbitrary bound, let's say $0.3$. All numbers of this sequence except the initial three are within $(1-0.3, 1+0.3)$. Let's take a tighter bound, $0.2$. All but the initial four are within $(1-0.2, 1+0.2)$. In fact, we can prove that for any positive $\epsilon$, only the initial <I-don't-know-how-many> elements are going to be outside $(1-\epsilon, 1+\epsilon)$, all the rest are within. That's why

$$1 = \mathsf{limit}(0, 0, 0.5, 0.75, 0.875, ...)$$

---

Footnotes:

0. It is provable that any two numbers that are a limit of the same sequence equal each other. Therefore, any sequence has at most one limit (but may have none if it diverges).

Comment: I should have at least commented on your post.  The reason why I didn't is because I don't see how it helps solve my issue.  I do understand limits and everything you posted as well.  I just want to know why how we can have a value of 1 using an index of n if there is no n to correlate to a final term to get summation of 1.

Comment: (0.) Thanks for your reply. Well, I'm out of ideas (sorry), so I guess it would be necessary for you to expand on why you think any such n is necessary (if you wish to continue the conversation). Because it is not. There is no "final term" that is hiding at the end of the infinite sequence that enters the equation. (1.) I'm also confused by your saying that you understand everything within my answer, but the answer ends with showing how from the definition of the sum, it follows the sum equals 1. How come?

Comment: @JozefMikuseinec to answer your first question, if there is no n to make the sum 2, then the sum never reaches 2.

Comment: To answer your second question, it is the definition of the sum that I am at odds with.  The definition seems to simply force the sum to equal 2, even though it does not quite get there.  It is weird that math would fudge this value like that.

Comment: "if there is no n to make the sum 2, then the sum never reaches 2". Well, a correct conclusion is that no *finite* portion of the sum reaches 1. But the infinite sum must be strictly greater than any its finite part, do you agree? And for any number $r$ less than 1, there is a finite portion of the infinite sum that is greater than $r$, right? So it follows that the infinite sum must be strictly greater than any number less than 1. It obviously cannot be greater than 1, so it has to be 1 exactly. That no finite portion of the sum equals 1 does not mean the infinite sum as a whole cannot.

Comment: @JosefMikusinec  That was very very well put.  I have been trying to find a logical argument like this for a very long time, thanks!  Now that I have established that the sum arrives at exactly 2, here is the burning question that I am desperately trying to understand: how does the point arrive at 2?  Is it the last summation, or the infiniti'ith summation?  If it is not the last summation of infinity, what could possibly bring the sum to the point that 2 occupies?

Answer (score 0):

Infinity can be a number in the way that 2 and 17 and 53126908 are.  Namely, in the set of hypernatural numbers $\mathbb N^\ast$, an infinite hypernatural, say $H$, is precisely a number greater than every standard natural number $n\in \mathbb N$.  The reason the expression $\sum_1^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}$ is taken to be exactly $1$ is because it is *defined* to be the [standard part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function) of the sum $\sum_1^H \frac{1}{2^n}$.  Applying the standard part discards the infinitesimal part of the sum.  In other words, it "rounds off" the sum to the nearest real number.

In the case at hand, applying the standard part has the effect of removing the *negative* infinitesimal you were puzzled about (in other words, the sum $\sum_1^H \frac{1}{2^n}$ is strictly smaller than $1$ as you expected, *before* the application of standard part.  For details see Keisler [*Elementary Calculus with Infinitesimals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_Calculus:_An_Infinitesimal_Approach).

The other *answers* talk about limits, but limit itself can be viewed as applying two operations: (1) evaluating at an infinite index $n=H$, and (2) applying standard part.

Unlike $\pi$, a hyperinteger $H$ shares all the first-order properties of the standard integers $1,2,3,\ldots$.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150045/discussion-on-answer-by-mikhail-katz-in-an-infinite-sum-is-there-an-actual-term); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.